# How to rotate vector towards another vector

Tags: opengl, math, rotation, rotational-matrices

I have a two 3D vectors `A`, `B` and the angle `alpha` between these two vectors. I would like to change this angle and rotate vector `B` by 3/7 of angle `alpha` towards vector `A`.

How can I do this in the simplest way?

My current approach is to create a matrix describing a plane based on on both vectors, then multiplying rotation matrix with angle 3/7 of alpha, where alpha is determined from cross product of `A` and `B`.

Well, it works, but I think it is an overkill and could be simplified. Any ideas?

Comment: Google **SLERP**.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the cross-product. This vector then is the basis for a quaternion rotation that goes 3/7alpha.

Under the hood though all of this will always boil down to the same maths. So if your solution works, encapsulate it into a function & be happy. And the matrix is advantageous (regardless of where you got it from, quaternion or by your means) because it can be composed with others, e.g. local to world coordinates.

Comment: Corrected. But why the downvote, because otherwise the answer is... incorrect?=

Comment: Ah, right, so I can use quaternion for this. I'll check it.